# Fill div with overflow content of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to build a book styled website where the content flows on two pages, but how can I build it in a way that the text from the one div, when it overflows, it goes to the next div and not just scrolled down?

I will need to implement this with wordpress as well in the end, so I will need to code something to do this for me. I need to make it work like this:

[image: website]

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Multiple columns of CSS3

for 2 columns use this code on the div class/id

```
#yourDiv{
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
    column-count:2;
}
```

if you want the text to be Justified like it is usual in books add `text-align:justify;` to
the code above.

if you want spacing between the columns use `column-gap:40px;`

for Firefox add `-moz-column-gap:40px;`

for Safari and Chrome add `-webkit-column-gap:40px;`

change the pixels according to your needs.